# C#: Periodically update GUI based on backgroundtask

Tags: c#, html, multithreading

I have a GUI that is for all intents and purposes really basic. A listview, an html form, and that's really it.

I want the user to have the following behavioral ability:

1 - Click a checkbox that says "Real-time". When clicked, a background thread will run once every 10 seconds.

2 - If there is a new file created (this is easy, to observe a new file) I want an alert displayed in my main gui. Where it is displayed for now is arbitrary (in a label, for example).

The main issue is I cannot figure out how to do this in a multi-threaded example. My goal is exactly in line with multithreading: do tasks 1 and 2, without locking task 1. Meaning, while the update check is running, the user can interact with the GUI as if nothing was going on in the background.

If you need more details to better answer this please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: I've  added HTML, please replace with  ASP.NET if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple sites I found useful for implementing a background worker when I needed to perform database operations while still allowing the GUI to be responsive:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw97wx20.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AsynchronousCodeBlocks.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use events from the thread to tell the UI that something's changed:

```
    // Just detected that that a new file has been created
    if (this.FileCreated_Event != null)
    {
        this.FileCreate_Event(this, new FileEventArgs(newFileName));
    }
```

where `FileCreated_Event` and `FileEventArgs` are declared appropriately.

Then in the UI when you receive the event you have the following:

```
this.fileChecker.FileCreated_Event += this.FileCreated_Event;
```

and:

```
    private void FileCreated_Event(object sender, TrackStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as Control).InvokeRequired)
        {
            (sender as Control).Invoke(action);
        }
        else
        {
            action();
        }
    }
```

where `action` is the thing you want to do.

Comment: @AustinSalonen - sorry about that - I managed to hit "enter" and post the answer before I'd finished it.

Comment: But what if the UI is ASP.NET? Seems unclear from the question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - That would make the UI end different, not sure how though as I've not done it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) tutorial. At the end I'm sure you'll be able to use threads. You must be careful though, because you'll have to manage those threads which can be a daunting task. I've never met a programmer who liked to debug multiple threads...